# Can VirtualBox run under Xen Dom0?

Tags: virtualbox, xen

I'd like to turn my Linux Mint desktop into Xen host.

Will I be able to use VirtualBox inside Dom0, just like without Xen? What the limitations would be (if any)?

I believe, that this might not be possible, since both VirtualBox and Xen utilizes CPU rings, and they might fall into conflict.

*Note, that I need to run VirtualBox under Dom0, not DomU.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this thread, titled: "[VirtualBox Running on top of XEN kernel, possible?](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/111354-virtualbox-running-on-top-of-xen-kernel-possible)" it sounds like the answer is no it isn't possible.

[image: ss 1]

[image: ss 2]

[image: ss 3]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not for the reasons you stated.

BUT:
You can run a Dom0 without hardware-VT within a VBox-VM. From there you can lauch DomUs in PV (not HVM) mode.

Comment: Will the XEN support VGA Passthrough then?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski I think so (on the Dom0), but this has changed - more recent xen-versions did a better support there. On the DomU I know that older (3.x) xen-versions did not support pass-through in PV-mode.